# Error: cannot find symbol method getDownloadUrl() of type com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.TaskSnapshot

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

Before gradle update everything worked fine, but later on this error popped up. I have referred to the official documents and it provides the same code.
[Not accepting the getDownloadUrl() method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLC2x.png)

I have added the correct dependency which is latest and the gradle sync is successful.
[app/build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/723Up.png)

This is the sample code provided in firebase docs which is same as mine.
[Firebase Assistant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGwQM.png)

I'm unable to understand what could possibly go wrong even if all required things are present. Stuck on this since 2 days, please help!

Answer (score 15):

As Doug pointed out, `UploadTask.getDownloadUrl()` is deprecated, so use  [StorageReference.getDownloadUrl()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#get_a_download_url).

But StorageReference.getDownloadUrl() returns Task, which must be handled asynchronously, you **cannot** do `Uri downloadUrl = photoRef.getDownloadUrl().getResult();` else you will get `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task is not yet complete`

Therefore, handle it asynchronously like this

```
 photoRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        Uri downloadUrl = uri;
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Upload success! URL - " + downloadUrl.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
```

Comment: I changed my code w.r.t. https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files?authuser=0

Comment: Where i need to add photoRef.putfile(filename); 
Please let me know??

Comment: @PrajwalW Have a look here -> https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#upload_from_a_local_file

Answer (score 10):

If you have a 'image_uri' and put it to the firebase storage  this code will help you.

```
private StorageReference storageReference= FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

 final StorageReference ref = storageReference.child("picture.jpg");
    ref.putFile(image_uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            ref.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                    final Uri downloadUrl = uri;


                }
            });
```

Comment: <UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> no longer provides 'getDownloadUrl' method, that is the reason the problem occured. Instead I did as specified here https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files?authuser=0

Comment: This answer is wrong. The [`StorageReference.getDownloadUrl()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference.html#getDownloadUrl()) method returns a `Task<Uri>`. So `ref.getDownloadUrl().toString()` call just gives you a string representation of the `Task`, not the actual URL. This answer shows the correct way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51076403

Comment: I just edited the above code. please check .That will work now.@FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 6):

`getDownloadUrl` no longer exists.

So the new method is:

```
final StorageReference ref = storageRef.child("images/mountains.jpg");
uploadTask = ref.putFile(file);

Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
    @Override
    public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
            throw task.getException();
        }

        // Continue with the task to get the download URL
        return ref.getDownloadUrl();
    }
}).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
        } else {
            // Handle failures
            // ...
        }
    }
});
```

[Firebase doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files?authuser=0)

Comment: I did it the same way. Thanks!

Comment: I want to use `onProgressListener` as well but I see that using this we dont have `onProgressListener` now as we have uri as result and not the `snapShot` itself..

Comment: What is uploadTask in the above code- uploadTask = ref.putFile(file);

Answer (score 5):

`UploadTask.getDownloadUrl()` is deprecated.  Use [StorageReference.getDownloadUrl()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference.html#getDownloadUrl()) instead.

Comment: Deprecation of this is true, but using those in older versions of applications never caused a problem, app never crashed! Considering a deprecation example, developers still use "ProgressDialog", even though it is deprecated it is still functional. That was my point!

Comment: storageReference.getDownloadUrl() working fine with '16.0.5'

Answer (score 2):

For kotlin

```
val uploadTask = fileReference.putFile(Uri.fromFile(primaryFile), metadata)
```

and

```
        uploadTask
                .addOnProgressListener { taskSnapshot ->

                }

                .addOnPausedListener { 

                }

                .addOnSuccessListener { taskSnapshot ->
                }
                .continueWithTask { task ->
                    if (!task.isSuccessful) {
                        throw task.exception!!
                    }
                 fileReference.downloadUrl
                }

                .addOnCompleteListener { task ->

                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        val downloadUrl: Uri = task.result

                    } else {
                        // Handle failures
                    }
                }

                .addOnFailureListener { e ->

                }
```

`val downloadUrl` is your URL that is uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

```
uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
@Override
public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
    filePath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            Map newImage = new HashMap();
            newImage.put("profileImageUrl", uri.toString());
            mDriverDatabase.updateChildren(newImage);

            finish();
            return;
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            finish();
            return;
        }
    });
}
```

});
**we can use get download url in this way because firebase do some changes **

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String LOG_TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

Button buttonUpload, buttonDownload;
RadioGroup radioGroup;
ImageView imageviewResult;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    buttonUpload = findViewById(R.id.upload_button);
    buttonDownload = findViewById(R.id.download_button);
    radioGroup = findViewById(R.id.radio_group);
    imageviewResult = findViewById(R.id.resultant_imageview);

    buttonUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            uploadImage();
        }
    });

    buttonDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            downloadImage();
        }
    });
}

private void uploadImage() {
    // Start by getting our StorageReference
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    StorageReference rootRef = storage.getReference();
    StorageReference bearRef = rootRef.child("images/bear.jpg");
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading");
    progressDialog.show();

    // Get the data from the image as bytes
    ImageView bearImage = getSelectedBearImage();
    bearImage.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    bearImage.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bitmap = bearImage.getDrawingCache();
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();

    // Upload it to our reference
    UploadTask uploadTask = bearRef.putBytes(data);
    buttonDownload.setEnabled(false);
    uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            // Handle unsuccessful uploads
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Upload failed: " + exception.getMessage());
        }
    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
            Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Download Url: " + downloadUrl);
            buttonDownload.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });
}

private void downloadImage() {
    // Start by getting a reference to the same location we uploaded to
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    StorageReference rootRef = storage.getReference();
    StorageReference bearRef = rootRef.child("images/bear.jpg");
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading");
    progressDialog.show();

    // Download our data with a max allocation of 1MB
    final long ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;
    bearRef.getBytes(ONE_MEGABYTE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
            // Convert bytes to bitmap and call setImageBitmap
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Download successful");
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            imageviewResult.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            // Handle any errors
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Download failed: " + exception.getMessage());
        }
    });
}

private ImageView getSelectedBearImage() {
    switch (radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
        case R.id.radio1:
            return findViewById(R.id.image_bear1);
        case R.id.radio2:
            return findViewById(R.id.image_bear2);
        case R.id.radio3:
            return findViewById(R.id.image_bear3);
        case R.id.radio4:
            return findViewById(R.id.image_bear4);
        default:
            return findViewById(R.id.image_bear1);
    }
}

}
```

activity.xml..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.adruser.firebasestorageapp.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="96dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_bear1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/a"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_bear2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/tiger"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/image_bear3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/download"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/image_bear4"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/add"/>
</LinearLayout>

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radio_group"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:checked="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RadioGroup>

<TextView
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Downloaded Image"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/resultant_imageview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/upload_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:text="Upload"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/download_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Download"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and i hope you connetcted with firebase storage and give internet permission..

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

more information refer this link..
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/image-upload-to-firebase-in-android-application--cms-29934

Comment: Thanks, but I did it using Task<Uri>

Comment: taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl(); not working in new Firebase Storage.