# Cannot resolve getDownloadUrl() Firebase

Tags: firebase, android-studio

can anybody help me? how to fix this.. the getdownloadurl() cannot resolve method

final String downloadUrl = task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to:

```
storageReference.child("YOUR_CHILD")
    .putFile("FILE")
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
             taskSnapshot
               .getStorage()
               .getDownloadUrl()
               .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                    //Put your result here
                                }
                            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is no longer supported if your project is updated to the latest version. I had the same problem earlier, I tried many ways altering the same  object. Instead I found out that firebase has changed the docs on their site and not in their Firebase Assistant. So, to save your time follow this link [Firebase Upload Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files?authuser=0)

and make necessary changes. It'll take 5 mins to change. 
If you want to confirm your problem with mine, here is the link [My Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50554548/error-cannot-find-symbol-method-getdownloadurl-of-type-com-google-firebase-st)

Answer (score 0):

for me based on the answer from @JPDroid
this is what worked

```
file_path.putFile(img_uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Object o) {
                                    String download_url = o.toString();
                                }
                            });
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error in Upload !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
```