# How to use getdownloadurl in recent versions?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

```
                Uri downloaduri=taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();//here i cant use getdownloadurl() function
                DatabaseReference new_prod=db.push();
                new_prod.child("product name").setValue(prod_name);
                new_prod.child("product price").setValue(prod_price);
                new_prod.child("available stock").setValue(prod_quan);
                new_prod.child("product image").setValue(downloaduri);
                pd.dismiss();//fragments code
```

I was unable to use getdownloadurl .I have already stored image in the firebase storage.Is it the fragment that is restricting the use of getdownloadurl? My motive is to make a query to store in firebase.please help me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl()` method was removed in recent versions of the Firebase Storage SDK. You will need to instead get the download URL from the `StorageReference` now.

Calling `StorageReference.getDownloadUrl()` returns a `Task`, since it needs to retrieve the download URL from the server. So you'll need a completion listener to get the actual URL.

From the [documentation on downloading a file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_data_via_url):

> ```
>  storageRef.child("users/me/profile.png").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
>     @Override
>     public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
>         // Got the download URL for 'users/me/profile.png' in uri
>         System.out.println(uri.toString());
>     }
> }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
>     @Override
>     public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
>         // Handle any errors
>     }
> });
> ```

Alternatively that first line could be this if you're getting the download URL right after uploading (as in your case):

```
taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
```

Also see:

- [Firebase Storage getDownloadUrl() method can't be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50660975/firebase-storage-getdownloadurl-method-cant-be-resolved)
- [Error: cannot find symbol method getDownloadUrl() of type com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.TaskSnapshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50554548/error-cannot-find-symbol-method-getdownloadurl-of-type-com-google-firebase-st)
- The example in the Firebase documentation on [uploading a file and getting its download URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#get_a_download_url)

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me after hours of research and differents ways :

```
filepath.putFile(resultUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
     @Override
     public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

           //here
           Task<Uri> urlTask = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
           while (!urlTask.isSuccessful());
           Uri downloadUrl = urlTask.getResult();

           final String sdownload_url = String.valueOf(downloadUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
storageReference.child("YOUR_CHILD")
    .putFile("FILE")
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener() {
       @Override
       public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
             taskSnapshot
               .getStorage()
               .getDownloadUrl()
               .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                    //Put your result here
                                }
                            });

                   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below method worked for me.

```
    _fbs_upload_success_listener = new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot _param1) {

                Task<Uri> urlTask = _param1.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                while (!urlTask.isSuccessful());
                Uri downloadUrl = urlTask.getResult();
                String _downloadUrl = downloadUrl.toString();
   };
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Kotlin Solution which worked for me after searching for 3 hrs

```
 val uploadTask =
        FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("images").child(imageName).putBytes(data)

    uploadTask.addOnFailureListener {
        // Handle unsuccessful uploads
        Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Failed to upload", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }.addOnSuccessListener {
        Toast.makeText(
            baseContext, "Image uploaded",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        ).show()
        var downloadUrl: Uri? = null
        FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("images")
            .child(imageName).downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener { it1 ->
            downloadUrl = it1 
          
        }


    }
```

**downloadUrl** is your URL