# error: incompatible types: Task<Uri> cannot be converted to Uri

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to fetch Url of the Image that I have uploaded in the Firebase. To fetch the Image I need to have the `Url` of the specific Image. But there's is problem occurring in the fetching. The Output box shows the following:

> error: incompatible types: Task cannot be converted to Uri

If I use `Task<Uri>` the image url become different. As compare to Uri.

```
  private void startPosting() {
    if (filePath != null) {
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading...");
        progressDialog.show();

        final StorageReference ref = mStorage.child("Quote_Image" + UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        ref.putFile(filePath)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(adminUpdateQuotesSend.this , "Uploaded" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        mDatbase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Quotes");
                        DatabaseReference newPost = mDatbase.push();
                        Uri down=ref.getDownloadUrl();
                            Uri dow=down;
                        newPost.child("ImageUrl").setValue(ref.getDownloadUrl());
                       // newPost.child("Positivity").setValue(PositiveDesc);
                    }
                })
                .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / taskSnapshot
                                .getTotalByteCount());
                        progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded " + (int) progress + "%");

                    }
                });

    }
}
```

The error is flashing on this line of code:

```
Uri down=ref.getDownloadUrl();
```

Comment: `getDownloadUrl` returns a task, which then gives you the download URL once it completes. For a code sample of how to do this, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51056397/how-to-use-getdownloadurl-in-recent-versions/51064689#51064689 and the longer: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#get_a_download_url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the following error:

> incompatible types: Task cannot be converted to Uri

Because `ref.getDownloadUrl()` return a `Task` object and not a `Uri` object. There is no way in Java to cast a `Task` object to a `Uri` object.

In order to get the download url, you need to use `addOnSuccessListener`, like in the following lines of code:

```
ref.putFile(filePath).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        ref.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                String url = uri.toString();

                //Do what you need to do with url
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Method does not override method from its superclass.
you are using onSuccess in a nested way. @AlexMamo

Comment: Yes but it should work. Please edit your question to see your changed code.

Comment: Yes you are right..  Thank you so much @AlexMamo

Answer (score 1):

Make sure if you are using a task to check for it if `isSuccessful()`

To get the download URL of the file you are uploading, you should run this inside a task like this one.

First, we do a reference where to store your file, then we run a task waiting for the result, if the result is true, in this case, we return the downloadUrl of the file, then when we `.addOnCompleteListener` , that's where we know we already have uploaded the file and have the URL, then we just check again if the upload process has been done correctly and we fetch the download URL of that file with

`Uri downloadUrl = task.getResult();` , since it's a URI, we can convert this url into an string like this `String downloadUrl = task.getResult().toString();`  or simply `downloadUrl.toString();`

```
final StorageReference ref = mStorage.child("Quote_Image" + UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    ref.putFile(filePath).continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
    @Override
    public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
            throw task.getException();
        }
        return ref.getDownloadUrl();
    }
    }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                 progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(adminUpdateQuotesSend.this , "Uploaded" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mDatbase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Quotes");
                    DatabaseReference newPost = mDatbase.push();
                     Uri downloadUrl = task.getResult();

                    newPost.child("ImageUrl").setValue(downloadUrl.toString());
                   // newPost.child("Positivity").setValue(PositiveDesc);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "upload failed: " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

The only thing is that `.addOnProgressListener` won't work here.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help..