# How to fix a error updating firebase dependencies

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm a **beginner** on Android. I updated all the dependencies of my Firebase project in the Android Studio gradle. But when compiling an apk, **this error appears:**

**`error: cannot find symbol method getDownloadUrl()`**

I've been trying to solve this problem for days, and I've decided to ask for help. I have already seen some tips on how to solve, but none worked for me. If anyone can give me a light, I thank you very much.

```
 //this will upload the user photo that he picked and generate a Small circle image and decode as base64
    public static void updateMyPhoto(final String imagePath, final OnComplete onComplete) {
        //generate new name for the file when uploading to firebase storage
        String fileName = UUID.randomUUID().toString() + Util.getFileExtensionFromPath(imagePath);
        //upload image
        FireConstants.imageProfileRef.child(fileName).putFile(Uri.fromFile(new File(imagePath)))
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        //get download url of the image
                        String downloadUrl = String.valueOf(taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl());
                        Map<String, Object> updateMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip

Comment: `getDownloadUrl` no longer exists on `UploadTaskSnapshot`, but is now available on `StorageReference`. See the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#get_a_download_url, and my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51056397/how-to-use-getdownloadurl-in-recent-versions/51064689#51064689

Answer (score 0):

by using `FireConstants` in method `onSuccess` you can find `getDownloadUrl()` method

```
FireConstants.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener
```

Comment: I tried now but it did not work :(