# Firebase Storage image upload successful through Android App but how to get url?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I have used  this library in my Android app

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:20.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:18.0.0'
```

And  this method use to upload my image on Firebase Storage:

```
 StorageReference storageRef = mStorage.getReference();
 finalStorageReference mountainsRef = storageRef.child("myImgName");

 Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File(myImgName));

UploadTask uploadTask = mountainsRef.putFile(file);

uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Handle unsuccessful uploads
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        Log.e(TAG, "img Error :" + exception.getMessage());
        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        //Log.e(TAG, "Task :" + taskSnapshot.getTask());

        //Log.e(TAG, "Class Store:" + taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl());
        Log.e(TAG,"metaData :"+taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getPath());

        // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type, etc.
        // ...
    }
}).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / taskSnapshot
                .getTotalByteCount());
        progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded " + (int) progress + "%");
    }
});
```

this code perfectly working for me to upload image. but how to know the image location url ?

Comment: Note that Cloud Storage for Firebase (originally called Firebase Storage) is not the same as Cloud Firestore. Storage is a file-storage solution, while the latter is a NoSQL database. You're calling the Storage API, so please tag accordingly (as I did)

Answer (score 2):

To get the download URL for a file in Cloud Storage, you call `getDownloadUrl()` on the `StorageReference` to that file. `getDownloadUrl()` returns a task, so you'll need to add a success listener to get the result.

```
mountainsRef.getStorage().getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
        // Got the download URL for 'users/me/profile.png' in uri
        System.out.println(uri.toString());
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Handle any errors
    }
});
```

For more on this, see:

- the sample in the [documentation on uploading a file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#get_a_download_url)
- the [documentation on downloading a file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_data_via_url)
- [How to use getdownloadurl in recent versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51056397/how-to-use-getdownloadurl-in-recent-versions)

Answer (score 0):

You can find your project's URL at the top of the Files section of Storage in the Firebase Console

```
 FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
 StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://example-firebase.appspot.com").child("android.jpg");
```

You can create a File object and attempt to load the file you want by calling getFile on your StorageReference with the new File object passed as a parameter. Since this operation happens asynchronously, you can add an OnSuccessListener and OnFailureListener

```
 try {
        final File localFile = File.createTempFile("images", "jpg");
        storageRef.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(localFile.getAbsolutePath());
                mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e ) {}
```

You can get the file's Url by using the getDownloadUrl() method on your StorageReference, which will give you a Uri pointing to the file's location.

```
storageRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
        Log.e("Image +", "uri: " + uri.toString());
        //Handle whatever you're going to do with the URL here
    }
});
```

Comment: Use the section which you need. Thanks