# download url is getting as com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@441922b while using taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl()

Tags: android, firebase-storage

I have to upload certain informations into realtime database. All details were uploaded correctly into it except image url. Using taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl() I got something like com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@441922b as image link. The file is uploaded in the storage. But I dont get the exact download url to access it. Codes are added below

Profileregistration.java

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.OnProgressListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class Profileregistration extends AppCompatActivity{

    EditText hname, phone, hlocation;
    ImageView image;
    String name,email,house,location,number,photostring;
    Button register;

    private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
    private Uri mImageUri;

    private StorageReference mStorageRef;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;

    private StorageTask mUploadTask;

    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profileregistration);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        hname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userreghouse);
        phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userregphone);
        hlocation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userreglocation);
        name = intent.getExtras().getString("name");
        email = intent.getExtras().getString("email");
        house = hname.getText().toString().trim();
        location = hlocation.getText().toString().trim();
        number = phone.getText().toString().trim();
        mProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

        mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("userdetails");
        mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("userdetails");

        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.userregprofilepic);
        image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openFileChooser();
            }
        });
        register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.regprofilebutton);
        register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mUploadTask != null && mUploadTask.isInProgress()) {
                    Toast.makeText(Profileregistration.this, "Upload in progress", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    uploadFile();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void openFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            mImageUri = data.getData();
            Picasso.with(this).load(mImageUri).into(image);
        }
    }

    private String getFileExtension(Uri uri) {
        ContentResolver cR = getContentResolver();
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        return mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(cR.getType(uri));
    }

    private void uploadFile() {
        if (mImageUri != null) {
            StorageReference fileReference = mStorageRef.child(phone.getText().toString().trim()
                    + "." + getFileExtension(mImageUri));

            mUploadTask = fileReference.putFile(mImageUri)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                            final Task<Uri> result = taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl();
                            result.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                    photostring = result.toString();
                                }
                            });
                            Handler handler = new Handler();
                            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    mProgressBar.setProgress(0);
                                }
                            }, 500);

                            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            String useremail=user.getEmail().replace("@","").replace(".","");

                            Toast.makeText(Profileregistration.this, "Upload successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Upload upload = new Upload(name,user.getEmail(),hname.getText().toString().trim(),hlocation.getText().toString().trim(),
                                    phone.getText().toString().trim(),result.toString());
                            String uploadId = useremail;
                            mDatabaseRef.child(uploadId).setValue(upload);
                            finish();
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Homewindow.class));
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(Profileregistration.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                            mProgressBar.setProgress((int) progress);
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No file selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Upload.java

```
public class Upload {
    private String mEmail;
    private String mPhone;
    private String mHname;
    private String mHlocation;
    private String mName;
    private String mImageUrl;

    public Upload() {
        //empty constructor needed
    }

    public Upload(String name,String email,String house,String location,String phone,String imageUrl) {
        if (name.trim().equals("")) {
            name = "No Name";
        }

        mName = name;
        mEmail = email;
        mHname = house;
        mHlocation = location;
        mPhone = phone;
        mImageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        mName = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return mEmail;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        mEmail = email;
    }

    public String getHname() {
        return mHname;
    }

    public void setHouse(String house) {
        mHname = house;
    }

    public String getHlocation() {
        return mHlocation;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        mHlocation = location;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return mPhone;
    }

    public void setmPhone(String phone) {
        mPhone = phone;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return mImageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        mImageUrl = imageUrl;
    }
}
```

I dont know why I am getting such error and also is there any error in codes.
Please help me.

Comment: Calling `StorageReference.getDownloadUrl()` returns a `Task`, since it needs to retrieve the download URL from the server. So you'll need a completion listener to get the actual URL. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51056397/how-to-use-getdownloadurl-in-recent-versions/51064689#51064689

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This will work when you have your image path from Firebase storage

```
StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("storage ref url in string");
storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                //do your stuff- uri.toString() will give you download URL\\
            }
        });
```

This will work when you are uploading the Image

```
 filepath.putFile(File).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot)
    {
         filepath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        Uri downloadUrl = uri;
                       //Do what you want with the url
                    }
        Toast.makeText(MtActivity.this, "Upload Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

For your code it will be something like this :

```
StorageReference fileReference = mStorageRef.child(phone.getText().toString().trim()
                    + "." + getFileExtension(mImageUri));

fileReference.putFile(File).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot)
        {
             filepath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            Uri downloadUrl = uri;
                           //Do what you want with the url
                        }
            Toast.makeText(MtActivity.this, "Upload Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: could you pls tell what is filepath here?

Comment: @JithinBabu check the last code filepath = StorageReference that's why i put last code for you just change putfile value so it will work for you.

Comment: Thankss.. It works..