# setImageResource() not fetching the image through Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I am using a recyclerview for my firebase project. Initially upon clicking on the recyclerview card it would display complete information about the card. But it works fine till the cardview. Upon clicking the card it displays all the information except the image. Changed the names of the class here for better understanding. Everything is displayed except the image.

**ImageAdapter.class**

```
package com.example.finalapkx;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.List;

public class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ImageViewHolder> {
    public Context mContext;
    private List<Upload> mUploads;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, List<Upload> uploads){
        mContext = context;
        mUploads = uploads;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.image_item,parent,false);
        return new ImageViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Upload uploadCurrent = mUploads.get(position);
        holder.textviewName.setText(uploadCurrent.getName());
        Picasso.get()
                .load(uploadCurrent.getImageUrl())
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .fit()
                .centerInside()
                .into(holder.imageViewand);

        holder.textviewDate.setText(uploadCurrent.getDate());

      holder.relativeLay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,Main3Activityand_retrieve_Detail.class);
                intent.putExtra("EventName",uploadCurrent.getName());
               intent.putExtra("ImageAndroid", uploadCurrent.getImageUrl());
                intent.putExtra("Date",uploadCurrent.getDate());
                intent.putExtra("Profile",uploadCurrent.getProfile());
                intent.putExtra("TargetedStudents",uploadCurrent.getTargetedStu());
                intent.putExtra("RegistrationLink",uploadCurrent.getReglink());
                intent.putExtra("OptionalLink",uploadCurrent.getReglinktwo());
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mUploads.size();
    }

    public class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView textviewName;
        public ImageView imageViewand;
        public TextView textviewDate;
        RelativeLayout relativeLay;
        public TextView textViewProfile;
        public TextView textViewReglink;
        public TextView textViewReglinktwo;
        public ImageViewHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            textviewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.androideventname);
            imageViewand = itemView.findViewById(R.id.androiduploadedimage);
            textviewDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.androideventdate);
            relativeLay = itemView.findViewById(R.id.layoutRelative);


        }
    }

}
```

**Detailedactivity.class**

```
package com.example.finalapkx;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextClock;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class Main3Activityand_retrieve_Detail extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView androidimgdetail;
    TextView andname,anddate,andprof,andreg,andregtwo,andTargetedStu;
    String adname, addate,adprof,adreg,adregtwo,adtargetedstu;
    int adimag;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3_activityand_retrieve__detail);
        androidimgdetail = findViewById(R.id.androiduploadedimage);
        andname = findViewById(R.id.andeventdetailid);
        anddate = findViewById(R.id.anddatedetailid);
        andTargetedStu = findViewById(R.id.andtargeteddetail);
        andprof = findViewById(R.id.andprofiledetail);
        andreg = findViewById(R.id.andreglinkdetail);
        andregtwo = findViewById(R.id.andreglinkdetail2);
        adname = getIntent().getStringExtra("EventName");
        addate = getIntent().getStringExtra("Date");
        adprof = getIntent().getStringExtra("Profile");
        adtargetedstu = getIntent().getStringExtra("TargetedStudents");
        adreg = getIntent().getStringExtra("RegistrationLink");
        adregtwo = getIntent().getStringExtra("OptionalLink");
        adimag = getIntent().getIntExtra("ImageAndroid",0);
        andname.setText(adname);
        anddate.setText(addate);
        andTargetedStu.setText(adtargetedstu);
        andprof.setText(adprof);
        andreg.setText(adreg);
        andregtwo.setText(adregtwo);
        androidimgdetail.setImageResource(adimag);
    }
}
```

**activity_detail**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Main3Activityand_retrieve_Detail">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ImageView
                android:background="@drawable/background_gradient"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/fake2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/layoutInput"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/background_white"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:text="Event Name"
            android:fontFamily="@font/mpb"
            android:textColor="#000">

        </TextView>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/andeventdetailid"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:text="Event Name"
                android:fontFamily="@font/mpb"
                android:textColor="#000">

            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:id="@+id/anddatedetailid"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:text="Date:"
                android:fontFamily="@font/mpb"
                android:textColor="#000">

            </TextView>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:text="Resource Person:"
                android:fontFamily="@font/mpb"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

            </TextView>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:id="@+id/androiduploadedimage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp">

            </ImageView>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:text="Profile"
                android:fontFamily="@font/mpb"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                >

            </TextView>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/andprofiledetail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:text="NULL"
                android:fontFamily="@font/mpb"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                >

            </TextView>
            <TextView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:text="Targeted Students:"
                android:fontFamily="@font/mpb"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

            </TextView>



            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/andtargeteddetail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:text="NULL"
                android:fontFamily="@font/mpb"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                >

            </TextView>
            <TextView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:text="Registration Link:"
                android:fontFamily="@font/mpb"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

            </TextView>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/andreglinkdetail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:text="NULL"
                android:fontFamily="@font/mpb"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

            </TextView>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:text="Optional Link:"
                android:fontFamily="@font/mpb"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                >

            </TextView>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/andreglinkdetail2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:text="NULL"
                android:fontFamily="@font/mpb"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                >

            </TextView>








        </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Where is this code using Firebase? If it's `uploadCurrent.getImageUrl()` please check the value of that URL. If it looks something like `com.google.android.gms.tasks`, you're getting the download URL from Cloud Storage wrong, and should get it as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51056397/how-to-use-getdownloadurl-in-recent-versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setImageResouse is used to access files from the drawable folder. To fetch images from Firebase use Piccasso

```
Picasso.get().load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

add this in your dependency

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```