# Firebase Cloud Storage task.getResult().getDownloadUrl not working in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase-storage

```java
Uri resultUri = result.getUri();
String current_userID = firebaseUser.getUid();

StorageReference filePath = mImageStorage.child("profile_images").child( current_userID + ".jpg");
filePath.putFile(resultUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            String downloadUrl = task.getResult().getDownloadUrl.toString();

            databaseReference.child("image").setValue(downloadUrl).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(AccountSettings.this, "Success Uploading", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(AccountSettings.this, "Error in Uploading", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
});
```

getDownloadUrl not working up with red line under it , or is the downloadUrl need to add in a method for it

Comment: I guess you need to write `getDownloadUrl()`. You forgot the brackets `()`.

Comment: You cannot get url this way. getDownloadUrl().toString() not working.  Follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60900650/8956604)

Comment: You must be working with a very old example.  Read the documentation for the correct details: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_data_via_url

Answer (score 0):

```
  String downloadUrl = task.getResult().getDownloadUrl.toString();
```

should be

```
  String downloadUrl = task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString();
```

Comment: That actually still won't work - there is no getDownloadUrl method on the object returned by getResult().