# GetDownloadUrl not working due to update in Firebase. Please help transform into the new version

Tags: android, firebase-storage

I am trying to implement photo storage in the Firebase storage database. The tutorial I was using shows it for an older version of firebase as a result there a slight error in the code. Please help me debug it. Please give me specific instructions/Changes since I am quite new at this and won't understand any generic command. Thank you

```
  private void saveUserInformation() {
        name = mNameField.getText().toString();
        phone = mPhoneField.getText().toString();

        Map userInfo = new HashMap();
        userInfo.put("name", name);
        userInfo.put("phone", phone);
        mCustomerDatabase.updateChildren(userInfo);
        if(resultUri != null){
            StorageReference filepath = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("profileImages").child(userId);
            Bitmap bitmap = null;

            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplication().getContentResolver(), resultUri);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20, baos);
            byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
            UploadTask uploadTask = filepath.putBytes(data);
            uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
            uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();  //THIS LINE GIVES ME THE ERROR

                    Map userInfo = new HashMap();
                    userInfo.put("profileImageUrl", downloadUrl.toString());
                    mCustomerDatabase.updateChildren(userInfo);

                    finish();
                    return;
                }
            });
        }else{
            finish();
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51056397/how-to-use-getdownloadurl-in-recent-versions

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl()
```

Comment: So replace the line that giving me an error with this one?

Comment: Yes replace taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl() on your code with the code above