# How can I save the URL of an image with Firebase in Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am trying to save the URL of an image by using the method below:

```
StorageReference filePath = imageStorage.child("profile_images").child(currentUserID + ".jpg");
filePath.putFile(resultUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
        if(task.isSuccessful())
        {
            String downloadURL = task.getResult().getStorage().getDownloadUrl().toString();
            userDataBase.child("image").setValue(downloadURL).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });


        }
        else
        {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Error Uploading",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
}
    String downloadURL = task.getResult().getStorage().getPath();
            userDataBase.child("image").setValue(downloadURL).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });


        }
        else
        {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Error Uploading",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

I am using Firebase API in Android Studio.
What I am trying to do is to upload an image by the user and save the URL to the database so later I can retrieve it from there.
But the method getDownloadUrl() does not return the URL, it returns this string instead:

```
com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@302097b
```

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Comment: Determining the download URL requires a call to the server. Because of this, the call to `getDownloadUrl()` returns a `Task` that completes when the download URL comes back from the server. You'll need to call `addSuccessListener()` on it to wait for it to complete. See the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_data_via_url) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51064689)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for your response, but I've tried to use the addSuccessListener() and I am getting the same result. Also tried to use the while loop like in the other post.

Comment: I'd recommend sticking to the/my accepted answer on that link, and the code from the documentation, neither of which uses a loop. Getting the same results with the code from those places seems highly unlikely, but if you can't get that code to work, update your question to show what you've tried.

Comment: The question is already marked as solved. Please do not add solution in an edit