# Firebase Storage fetching image by the reference

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I have a small problem with fetching my image on the Firebase Database Storage.
The Database has the reference of that image and it is the reference which gets fetched. How can I can the image using that reference? I have tried both Picasso and Glide to display the image on on the image view , but since it is the reference that gets fetched it won't display the image.

[image: Reference]

And this is the log message displayed for this.

[image: Log Messages]

Thank you!

Comment: That's isn't a correct URL. Most likely that's why you have that behavior. Show us your code.

Comment: It looks like you're doing `String downloadURL = storageRef.getDownloadURL()` somewhere, which won't work. Getting a storage URL is an asynchronous operation, and you need to attach a completion/success listener to get the result See the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_data_via_url) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51064689)